# Access Linq Output in MVC Controller itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i just want to fetch monthwise(only last 2 months) total and want to compare the total of both records in controller and than show the result in view.

```
var currRev = (from p in dbObj.gen
                       group p by new { p.pdate.Year, p.pdate.Month } into grp
                       select new
                       {
                           Year = grp.Key.Year,
                           Month = grp.Key.Month,
                           total = grp.Sum(a => a.total_revenue)
                       }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Year).ThenBy(a => a.Month).Take(2).ToList();
```

dbObj is my context class, gen is my table. Query is working fine but how can i compare the output values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so now you have a anonymous with Year, Month  and total . you can use currrev to compare it to whatever values you want to compare . Also please post a complete detail question like after this query what code are you executing and what is not working it will help to answer .

Comment: Hi Yashveer thanks for replying. The entire code is very long. Os i have mentioned the requirement. I dont know how i compare the 2 value in currRev with each other. This query is working fine if i display it as its in view, But i want to compare the total of 2 months and then show the % increase or decrease in view.

Comment: hi I tried to write it I think it will give u a good start answer id not complete as I didnt find enough time but I hope from this you have anyidea wht u can do .

Answer (score 0):

hi i have modified my question. I have this code in my controller which is working fine. It simple fetches the current month Revenue from gen table, stores in Viewbag and than displays on view. It is working perfectly, But now requirement changed. I have to display this fig along with the increment or decrement value from last month. I have gen table in model class with many fields. But here i used pdate and total_revenue.

```
    datamasterEntities dbObj = new datamasterEntities();
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var currRev = from p in dbObj.gen
                where p.pdate.Month == Date.Now.Month && p.pdate.Year==Date.Now.Year
                select new
                {
                    total = p.total_revenue
                };
        var cTotal = currRev.Sum(p => p.total).ToString();

        if (cTotal != "")
        {                
            ViewBag.currRevenue = Convert.ToDecimal(cTotal).ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yashveer for your valuable time, Let me try this.

Comment: it gives me Null. Actually i need to pass the result to viewbag so that the same can be displayed there. I want the current month total and the %increase or decrease from old month. This is the one i am using in my dashboard screen developing in MVC.

Comment: this code is wrriten in console application to show how compare . you need to incoprate in in your mvc . I didnt have you all model classes so i made my own class you neeed to update code as per you class